# Active Directory B2C Logout: what is the purpose then?

Tags: wpf, azure-ad-b2c, logout, azure-ad-graph-api

At the moment I'm still studing a solution for implementing the ADB2C logout for my desktop application (we implemented the Access tokens (used for implicit flows)). So far what I discovered is making me very confused about the purpose of the Logout feature in AD B2C (and probably in OpenId as well?). I realize the following things:

1. Log out process doesn't revoke the id tokens already issued
2. nothing stops a blocked user from using their refresh token (granted before the block) to get another access code, and continue to do so until they sign out themselves (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/75189/azure-b2c-revoke-refresh-tokens.html))
3. From [this link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35370) (actually the same..) they suggest to use the Azure Graph command "invalidateAllRefreshTokens", but from the [Official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-invalidateallrefreshtokens?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) seems is still in beta and is not supported in production.

So at the moment I'm wondering what is the real purpose of using the signout process. Seems I should take care of it all by my self (and that's fine), but should I still need to call the signout endpoint? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore#sign-out) they say:
`If your app didn't go to the logout endpoint, the user will reauthenticate to your app without entering their credentials again. The reason is that they'll have a valid single sign-in session with the Microsoft identity platform.` But at the moment I can't understand this sentence (probably bacause I'm still a little bit shocked from all these bad news). So my question is: how do you complete your logout process? Is there any considerations I shoud pay attention while I'm logging out from my desktop app? Thanks for your patience and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the logout endpoint, a few things happen:

1. Access and Refresh tokens are destroyed by the client or confidential server
2. AAD B2C Session cookies are cleared

The point of the logout here is such that when the legitimate user requests to logout on a specific device, to login again, the user MUST provide credentials. Imagine a shared device in a family home, or in a library. Users must logout to protect THEMSELVES.

Everything you have stated concern over is in reference to a legitimate user who captures their tokens and replays them. That is not a concern when the user IS the one who authenticated in the first place, and IS the one who could reauthenticate anyway to obtain those tokens.

If your concern is around YOU as an ADMIN forcing the end user to lose complete access because YOU demand it, that is not achieved by the USER voluntarily logging out, it is determined by YOU as an ADMIN calling the /revoke endpoint on demand (albeit the AAD B2Cs session cookie will not be invalidated, only the refresh token/s).

In this case, the user will remain logged in until their Access Token expires. And if the account is marked as disabled at time of token revocation, they will not be able to authenticate again regardless. If this scenario is paramount to your service to operate securely, you want to reduce the Access Token lifetime (minimum: 5min).

Comment: How does this prevent others using the shared device from logging into the account of the previous user?

Comment: Because all local artifacts (cookies/tokens) are destroyed.